# How to create a new component in Apache OFBiz latest version 16.11.01?

Tags: ofbiz

Does someone know how we can create a new component in Apache OFBiz latest version 16.11.01. Earlier it was using `ant create-component` to create a component but the new version uses Gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new command is:

```
gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=myplugin
```

where `myplugin` is the name of the new component. Please refer to the `README.md` file in the OFBiz home folder for further details, in the section "Create a new plugin". Once the component is created, you should load its data (required to grant access rights to the `admin` user); you can easily do this by loading the demo data of OFBiz with the command:

```
gradlew loadDefault
```

You can also delete the component with the command:

```
gradlew removePlugin -PpluginId=myplugin
```

Comment: I am able to create a component by the above command but after creating component when i am going to the component, an error is occurred  as ofbiz.widget.renderer.ScreenRenderException

Comment: Bruno, can you please provide a screenshot or full stacktrace?
How do you access the new component?

Comment: I just checked the functionality with latest trunk and the command Jacopo provided. It works a charm (after removing the MYPLUGIN base permission in ofbiz-component.xml).

Comment: This is the error I am getting [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlaTu.png

Comment: @JacopoCappellato there was a problem in uilabels. I got it done by keeping english translations and clearing all others.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are standard OFBiz components that reside in the specialpurpose directory. Plugins can be added manually or fetched from a maven repository. The standard tasks for create new plugin is giving below.

To Create a new plugin. The following project parameters are passed:

- **pluginId**: mandatory
- **pluginResourceName**: optional, default is the Capitalized value of pluginId
- **webappName**: optional, default is the value of pluginId
- **basePermission**: optional, default is the UPPERCASE value of pluginId

Enter following command below to create component/plugin,

```
./gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=myplugin
```

or

```
./gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=myplugin -PpluginResourceName=MyPlugin -PwebappName=mypluginweb -PbasePermission=MYSECURITY`
```

The above commands achieve the following:

- create a new plugin in /specialpurpose/myplugin
- add the plugin to /specialpurpose/component-load.xml

Once the component is created, you should load its data (required to grant access rights to the "admin" user);

```
./gradlew "ofbiz --shutdown"
./gradlew loadDefault
./gradlew
./gradlew ofbiz
```

To know more about create component in ofbiz
[Create ofbiz component/plugin by gradle](https://ikziko.blogspot.com/2017/03/create-ofbiz-component-plugin_15.html)